# Do conditional probabilities always form valid distributions?

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability

For example, if $p(A, B, C, D, \dots)$ is a valid joint distribution of random variables (that is, the function is $\geq 0$ for every point in its support and the function sums to $1$), is $p(A \mid B, C, D, \dots$) also a valid distribution? What about when one of the random variables is set to a specific value like $p(A \mid B=b, C, D, E, \dots)$?

Comment: I think this is answered on this site before, but cannot find it ...

Comment: Isn't the answer "yes, this is an automatic consequence of the definition of conditional distributions"?  If no, then please share with us your definition so we can see what work might be needed.